# Load php page with $.get when I click using jquery

Tags: jquery, get

I am running the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $(this).get("auth.php",{username: $('#log').val(), password: $('#pwd').val()});
    });
});
```

Here is the html

```
<form class="clearfix" action="#" method="post">
    <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <label class="grey" for="log">Username:</label>
    <input class="field" type="text" name="log" id="log" value="" size="23" />
    <label class="grey" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input class="field" type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="23" />
    <label><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login"/>
    <a class="lost-pwd" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
</form>
```

although when I click the input with the id submit the page just reloads even though auth.php redirects to another site when its is run separately.

I can get the alert to show me that it is responding to the click event and the message in the alert contains the correct values for the boxes but it seems that the $.get never opens auth.php

Comment: Why are you using jquery for this if you want the page to refresh ? Why not post directly ?

Comment: You might need to cancel the submit with `return false` otherwise the browser will submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

A few things wrong with your code. First off it's `$.get` and not `$(this).get`. Next you probably want to prevent the default action, although i can't tell if you want to or not in your case, it seems you're expecting the page to refresh which will not happen if you cancel the default action, usually you use ajax when you want to refresh parts of the page and prevent a full refresh. If you're expecting the page to refresh/redirect then why are you using ajax in the first place ? Why not do a straight up post ?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.get("auth.php",{username: $('#log').val(), password: $('#pwd').val()});
        e.preventDefault(); 
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `return false;` in your form to stop the form submission, you just added a `.click` fn to the submit button. But the form STILL submits.